# setContentView() in Dialog not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, setcontentview

I am using a custom dialog in my app:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState ?: Bundle())

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null)

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list)
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        setCancelable(true)
        setUpRecyclerView(view)
    }
```

I am passing the layout name in `setContentView()` function.

But when I click on the dialog it displays nothing.

However if I pass the `view` object inside `setContentView` it displays everything.

Why wasn't it displaying when I typed `setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list)`

Comment: Where is this code? Inside a `DialogFragment`? Shouldn't you override `onCreateView` and inflate the layout there?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the very beginning. The best approach to show custom dialogs I think it's to extend DialogFragment and then inflate your layout in `onCreateView` (like when u creating Fragments).
So your coe should look like this:

```
            public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
            Button myButton;
    
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, container,false);
                //here o initialize your variables
                myButton = mView.findViewById(R.id.my_button_id)
                return mView;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
                //here u can set listeners or do some things like text changes etc
                myButton.setOnClickListener(v -> dismiss());
            }
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
//and here u can change dialog layouts position anda else
                Dialog dialog = getDialog();
                 if(dialog != null){
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

After that u simply can create instance of your dialog and show it

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.show
```

Comment: The code is good, but my question is why should I inflate layout all the time? Why cant I pass the layout resource id? `setContentView()` also accepts layout resource id

Comment: You would need to find the person on the Android team who wrote the original fragment. We can't really answer questions about why a developer made a certain choice.

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine for me!

```
fun showProgressDialog(){

        mProgressBar = Dialog(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog)
        mProgressBar.setCancelable(false)
        mProgressBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        mProgressBar.show()
    }
```

this is the function I'm using...